# Can't send password containing special characters(replaced with space)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to send password containing special characters. For example: password containing abc+ ends up as abc(space) on the server side which is wrong, breaking the elephant ahead. The server is not guilty as I've checked the network and the angular does actually send to server 'abc ' with space instead of 'abc+'. So the issue is on the client side code.

```
 login: function (param) {
                        var data,
                            config = {
                                headers: {
                                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'

                            },
                            ignoreAuthModule: 'ignoreAuthModule'
                        };

                    data = 'j_username=' + param.username + '&j_password=' + param.password + '&_spring_security_remember_me=' + param.rememberMe + '&submit=Login';
                    if (!angular.isUndefined(param.service)) {
                        data += '&service=' + param.service;
                    }

                    $http.post('app/authentication', data, config).success(
                        function (data, status, headers, config) {
                            $rootScope.registrationSuccess = false;
                            $rootScope.authenticationError = false;
                            $rootScope.userLocked = false;
                            if (param.success) {
                                param.success(data, status, headers, config);
                            }
                        }
                    ) ...
```

When I debug the code j_password actually has 'abc+'. Some of the configuration is wrong I guess. Help poor java developer pls.

Comment: You should UrlEncode (or Base64) encode the parameters. You can do this with [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp).

Comment: `encodeURIComponent(param.username)` etc

Comment: Not sure I can help with the elephant however.

Comment: Thanks :-). The elephant is the CAS server, CAS proxy, CAS client and dozen of Spring Security components. Which is where I thought the problem was.

Comment: Ah, another java developer trying to write javascript... ;)

Comment: mostly happens when our UI devs are 'too busy drawing bootstrap boxes and trying to sign contract with devil - IE 7'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should encode the parameters using encodeURIComponent.  For example,

```
data = 'j_username=' + encodeURIComponent(param.username) + '&j_password=' + encodeURIComponentparam.password) + '&_spring_security_remember_me=' + encodeURIComponent(param.rememberMe) + '&submit=Login';
```

Comment: If smbdy is forwarding request like me via restTemplate then I recommend org.yaml.snakeyaml.util.UriEncoder to send multipart form encoded data. (you are using yml anyway right? :-))